# Something disables all events on a textbox in IE11?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I've got a totally weird scenario. It might be a browser bug. The problem is that I've not been able to create a minimal scenario with which to reproduce it. It's easy to reproduce in the actual application, but I don't have anything to show you...

Here's how it goes:

I have a Devexpress gridview which contains many textboxes. On `blur` the textboxes make an AJAX request and display a full-page modal spinner for the duration of the request (implemented with a Devexpress popup).

If I exit the textbox by clicking on another textbox (cue an AJAX request and a brief flash of spinner), the next textbox will act as if all events on it are disabled. They just don't trigger. However, if I exit that textbox and re-focus it, all events work again as normally.

I've attached to multiple events (`keydown`, `keyup`, `change`, `blur`) and with multiple methods (`addEventListener` and inline in HTML). Nothing works until I refocus the textbox.

Even weirder, the IE's own little "x" mark doesn't show on the textbox as it normally does. What I mean is this thing:

[image: Good textbox]

When the events are disabled however, it looks like this:

[image: Bad textbox]

But the textbox *itself* still works. I can type in it just fine. Just no events and no "x" mark. Unfocus it, refocus it, and all is normal again.

Frankly, I've no idea how to get such an effect (the lack of "x") even if I wanted to. I know it's connected both to the AJAX request and the full-screen blocking spinner, because if I remove either of them the effect goes away. Also, this only happens in IE - Chrome works fine.

The question is - **what could produce this and how to work around it?** My current best idea is to make a different modal spinner (the Devex popup seems to have a high performance overhead anyway) and hope that makes it go away.

I wish I could provide a clean example for you, but since a whole truckload of Devexpress and ASP.NET magic is involved inbetween, it's pretty difficult.

Comment: Do F12 Tools see something?  Is your HTML valid (sometimes there are strange effects with invalid HTML)?

Comment: @TGlatzer - as the deadline is pretty pressing, I already "fixed" it by changing the spinner. The problem is gone and the site feel snappier too. As for HTML validity - I'm pretty sure it's not - ASP.NET webforms rarely generates a valid HTML. However the violations are typically minor (like a `<div>` within a `<span>`, omitting `alt=""` for images and the like).